# Using a form to update an instance variable in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm sure there is a very simple answer to this, but I'm struggling to figure it out. Timesheet has_many Runs, and a Run belongs_to a Timesheet. On my Timesheet#show page I'd like to have a select box that is populated only with @timesheet.runs. Is it possible to have a user select an option from the select box, which then updates an instance variable in the TimesheetController?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What instance variable? A code snippet would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the values from the form just come across as a hash. You can access its values and assign them to any variable, like any other hash. The only thing special about the `params` hash is that it's automatically generated from your form, which is convenient.

So, if you have a form with a select with an id of "runs", then in your controller, if you want to assign the value of that select to a variable called `run_value`:

```
def update
  run_value = params[:runs]
end
```

Or, your form might also have an `id` of, say, `timesheet`, in which case your controller would look something like:

```
def update
  run_value = params[:timesheet][:runs]
end
```